# I'm trying to identify a short science fiction story from the 60s or 70s. Title and author unknown

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I can remember only two incidents from the story:

1. Large machines are watched emerging from the sea up a beach (This is not John Wyndham's *The Kraken Wakes*!).
2. At the end it is announced that God is a huge beetle living on the dark side of the moon.

Comment: Can you tell us about the tone? Point 2 could be comedy or horror.

Comment: Thanks for your question. It wasn't either comedy or horror exactly - more tongue-in-cheek. Maybe more of a satire on society. As I recollect, the god bit was almost a throwaway comment at the end of the story.

Comment: Were the machines emerging from the sea piloted by dolphins, who were the new species favored by God? I recall an odd short story along those lines.

Comment: Thanks Otis. That sounds an interesting possibility. I can't say I remember the dolphin angle but it does ring very faint bells. Whether it's my story or not, that does sound like a great plot-line! If you recall any more details, please let me know. Adrian Buckley

Comment: I think I remember this. At the end it was noted that the beetle was so heavy, it was pressing down on the world.

Comment: The dolphins story is described here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166537/dolphins-invade-the-land-with-weird-religious-angle/166614#166614