# Dolphins invade the land (with weird religious angle)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short story that I read perhaps 5-10 years ago. The plot is strange: God has given up on humans and is causing dolphins to take over the Earth, but first, all the people are compelled to kill each other to make room.

The story is told from the viewpoint of a person who I think is one of the last survivors (or perhaps the very last). In the final scene he sees the dolphins emerging from the ocean en masse, knowing that there's no hope for him. I don't remember if the dolphins are using some sort of technological suits or if they have just been physically changed so that they can walk.

There's some strange angle where God has <strike>been physically located out in space and is perhaps irritated by this</strike> has arrived within the solar system in response to the dolphin's prayers, which I think is why humans are being wiped out.

This was definitely a short story and not the Roy Meyers trilogy mentioned in another answer. It was very dark in tone and seems related in my mind to "For I Am A Jealous People" by Lester Del Rey. I want to say that I read them in the same collection, but none of the ones listed for that story on ISFDB seem right, so the connection may just be that they have a similar main idea.

This was mostly a weird story more than straight sci-fi, but I definitely would have read it as part of a sci-fi collection.

Comment: This story has just been republished on Amazon in the anthology called Tales of the Continuing Time and other Stories by Daniel Keys Moran.  It's his first new book in years.  His entire back list is now available on Kindle.

Comment: The title reminded me of a Simpson Horror Shows episode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is "Given the Game" by Daniel Keys Moran, Aboriginal Science Fiction, November/December issue, 1990.

Here is the last paragraph of the story:

> There was a flicker of a smile in the back of Costigan's mind, the
> taste of primordial anger and ancient amusement, followed by a brief
> flash of God's countenance, of rows upon rows of crystalline sharp
> teeth.
>
> "Now they have hands", said God. "Now they will learn to Play. And
> when they have practiced long enough, We will return for them. And
> give them the Game."
>
> Darkness descended upon Costigan. "Death is not a game. Death is
> not..."
>
> "All things are the Game. Join Us. Let it go."  Costigan released his
> body.
>
> Behind him the dolphins were coming up out of the ocean.

Comment: I'm certain I've never read the collection that is the only known publication for this story at ISFDB. Still, the last paragraph you quoted sounds promising. I hate to ask, but can you provide any other quotes that reinforce this answer?

Comment: It's not a collection.  It was a magazine, long out of publication.  I'll try to remember more of the story but I only read it a few times.

Comment: It looks like the author released it as freeware.  http://www.self.gutenberg.org/wplbn0000670584-given-the-game-by-moran-daniel-keys.aspx?

Comment: That's totally it -- nice find! It's more disturbing than I remembered, and I can't imagine where I came across it.